# Regex contains runaway part

Tags: javascript, regex, string, parsing

I'm building a Regex to parse some "filter strings". String which contains conditions which have to match, combined by "and" or "or" operators.
For this I needed a regex which searches for matching brackets.¨

A filter string can look like this:
`(param2="def" or param2="ghj") and param1="abc"`

It works as expected, but if I enter a typo, like a newer closing bracket, I receive an error for "Runaway Regular Expression"

The part of the regex which is looking for matching brackets:
`/\(((?:[^)(]+|\((?:[^)(]+|\([^)(]*\))*\))*)\)/`

If I test this regex with following string `(description=r\"Sending \[A-Z0-9]{8}\")`, and if I add a opening bracket "(" anywhere inside, it's throwing the error.

Especially in JavaScript I'm not sure if there is a way to catch this error.

Regex Demo: https://regex101.com/r/eE6mX3/1

Comment: If you want to support just two nested levels you need to write it as `\([^()]*(?:\([^()]*(?:\([^()]*\)[^()]*)*\)[^()]*)*\)`, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/nxnWWb/1).

Comment: Regex is not a good tool for parsing these strings if you can have infinite nesting in them: `a=1 or (b=2 or (c=3 or (d=4 or (e=5 or (f=6 and g=7)))))`

Comment: Have you tried dropping the `+` quantifier in your pattern?

Comment: @bobblebubble Which + quantifier? If I drop the first one, he will not match anymore the outer brackets, but takes the inner ones.

Comment: @VLAZ My idea was to parse it recursively by taking first the outer condition, and recall the same function with the inner ones. I added the whole code in the main post.

Comment: If I [test this input (DEMO)](https://regex101.com/r/Dsmvvx/1), it times out. [Without the `+`quantifier it doesn't time out (DEMO)](https://regex101.com/r/Dsmvvx/2). Maybe I misread problem :)

Comment: Oh I see! I'm sorry I think I misunderstood your answer! Many thanks it seems to work! With a "^" in front it doesn't match anything anymore if the brackets are wrongly set, and I can catch a faulty filter. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-write the pattern so that it matched:

- a `(` char

  - any chars other than `(` and `)`
  - zero or more occurrences of

    - a `(` char
    - any chars other than `(` and `)`
    - a `)` char
    - any chars other than `(` and `)`

This way, the pattern will be as efficient as possible:

```js
\([^()]*(?:\([^()]*\)[^()]*)*\)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZEC2kv/2).